# some urdu letters in tkinter entry widget

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, urdu

I am working on a GUI Urdu language software with tkinter, I have a problem with entry widget, entry widget changes at leates these two letters when they are directly typed in entry widget.

```
ی
ۃ

with
ي
?
```

The same problem is noticed in Text widget.
can any one give solution of this bug in tkinter ?
Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be possibly relevant: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/02/14/531572.html (the two characters mentioned are your first example, and the character it turns into).

Comment: @ jasonharper Yes it is partially relevant , but it is only describing the problem not the solution, i am looking for posible solution, so i can complete my project otherwise i have to leave tkinter or perhapes python itself.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the string in the Entry Box, you can easily replace it:

```
name = ent.get()
name = name.replace(‘ی’,’ي’)
```